# Semantic UI styled issue

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, semantic-ui-react

I can add some styles to the Menu component. But how can I add style to the Menu.Item component?

```
const LayoutHeader = styled(Menu)`
  && {
    background: red;
  }
`
```

Comment: what do you want to do ?

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi I just want to add some styles to Menu.Item component (default semantic-ui component) with styled components

Comment: something like this : https://codesandbox.io/s/92kmxo7l2w

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```js
const LayoutHeaderItem = styled(Main.Item)`
  &&&{
    /* your code  */
  }
`;
```